# Scan/Record application's outgoing ip request's?

Tags: networking, ip

How can I scan/record IP requests from a specific application. The less extra software and less GUI, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [*packet sniffer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_sniffer).

There are plenty of options, but your best choice depends on your specific needs. If you only want to see the connections, then [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) or [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) will do the trick.

If you want to actually capture/see the data, then you need something a little more heavy-duty.

- [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the perennial favorite and quite powerful, with lots of options.
- Microsoft’s own [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865), is also powerful, but is not the easiest to use.
- My own go-to sniffer is [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) because it is extremely easy to use, especially for quick capture/monitor sessions, and it has a minimal interface.